# Búsquedas Condicionadas - Error La conexión sigue abierta

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente código, donde me funciona pero después de una búsqueda me dispara el error de que la conexión sigue abierta y me detiene el programa, pero no veo donde este el error, por que según veo la abro y la cierro bien.

```
private void btnbuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                string cadsql = "Select * from maestraproductoinventario where [Codigo De Articulo]='" + txtcodigo.Text + "'";

                SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(cadsql, con);
                con.Open();

                SqlDataReader leer = comando.ExecuteReader();
                if (leer.Read() == true)
                {
                    txtdescripcion.Text = leer["Descripcion"].ToString();
                    txtmarca.Text = leer["Marca"].ToString();
                    txtreferencia.Text = leer["Referencia"].ToString();
                    txtexistencia.Text = leer["Existencia"].ToString();
                    txtpreciopieza.Text = leer["Precio de Venta"].ToString();

                    txtdescripcion.Enabled = true;
                    txtmarca.Enabled = true;
                    txtreferencia.Enabled = true;
                    txtexistencia.Enabled = true;
                    txtmateriales.Enabled = true;
                    txtcantidadvendida.Enabled = true;
                    txtmanoobra.Enabled = true;
                    textBox10.Enabled = true;
                    txtcodigo.Enabled = false;
                    btnbuscar.Enabled = false;
                    txtmateriales.Select();
                }
            else
            {
                DialogResult mensaje = MessageBox.Show("¿Desea Indagar el Codigo del producto?", "Producto No encontrado", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (mensaje == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    MaestradeDispositivosoInventario frm = new MaestradeDispositivosoInventario();
                    frm.Show();
                }
                else if (mensaje == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    txtcodigo.Clear();
                    txtcodigo.Select();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: ¿Samuel podrías compartir donde defines con? Creo que podrías tener un código más optimizado si utilizas `using` para definir tanto la conexión, como el comando y el  `datareader`, y evitarías este rollo de que la conexión quede abierta.

Comment: si defino un using.. no me lee el codigo del string cadsql me dispara este error:"No puede ser una declaración o declaración etiquetada" o en ingles "embedded stament cannot be a declaration or labeled statement"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás cerrando la conexión en el bloque del else. Cierra la conexión al final del método.

```
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(cadsql, con);
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader leer = comando.ExecuteReader();
        if (leer.Read() == true)
        {
            txtdescripcion.Text = leer["Descripcion"].ToString();
            txtmarca.Text = leer["Marca"].ToString();
            txtreferencia.Text = leer["Referencia"].ToString();
            txtexistencia.Text = leer["Existencia"].ToString();
            txtpreciopieza.Text = leer["Precio de Venta"].ToString();

            txtdescripcion.Enabled = true;
            txtmarca.Enabled = true;
            txtreferencia.Enabled = true;
            txtexistencia.Enabled = true;
            txtmateriales.Enabled = true;
            txtcantidadvendida.Enabled = true;
            txtmanoobra.Enabled = true;
            textBox10.Enabled = true;
            txtcodigo.Enabled = false;
            btnbuscar.Enabled = false;
            txtmateriales.Select();
        }
    else
    {
        DialogResult mensaje = MessageBox.Show("¿Desea Indagar el Codigo del producto?", "Producto No encontrado", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (mensaje == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            MaestradeDispositivosoInventario frm = new MaestradeDispositivosoInventario();
            frm.Show();
        }
        else if (mensaje == DialogResult.No)
        {
            txtcodigo.Clear();
            txtcodigo.Select();
        }
    }
        con.Close();
}
```

Edito:

Te añado un bloque using para que puedas cambiar el modo en el que te conectas a una base de datos. Con el bloque using obligas a que la conexión haga un dispose y se cierre:

```
        using (var con = new SqlConnection("AquiTuCadenaDeConexion"))
        {
            con.Open();
            //Aquí dentro hago todo lo que necesite
            //por ejemplo
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TestTable", con))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var testing = reader.GetString(1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Igualmente te dejo un enlace a un blog que lo explica de modo fantástico.

http://thatcsharpguy.com/post/usos-using-2/

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Darío podrías copiar el código e indicarle al OP dónde sería mejor colocar el `con.Close()`. De hecho hasta a mi me cuesta identificar donde colocarlo debido a los brackets jaja.

Comment: Tengo que aprender a usar esta página mejor. Es muy útil, pero me lio a la hora de copiar y pegar código. Vamos allá ;)

Comment: probe moverlo de lugar y aun sigue haciendo lo mismo

Comment: En ese caso, prueba a utilizar la conexión dentro de un bloque using, de ese modo te aseguras de que la conexión se cierre.

Comment: De todos modos, asegúrate de que no tengas más conexiones abiertas en otras partes del código.

Answer (score 4):

Yo usaria using para no tener ese tipo de problemas, al terminar el bloque la conexion se cerraria automaticamente

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
....
....
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(cadsql, con);


    SqlDataReader leer = comando.ExecuteReader();
    if (leer.Read() == true)
    {
        txtdescripcion.Text = leer["Descripcion"].ToString();
        txtmarca.Text = leer["Marca"].ToString();
        txtreferencia.Text = leer["Referencia"].ToString();
        txtexistencia.Text = leer["Existencia"].ToString();
        txtpreciopieza.Text = leer["Precio de Venta"].ToString();

        txtdescripcion.Enabled = true;
        txtmarca.Enabled = true;
        txtreferencia.Enabled = true;
        txtexistencia.Enabled = true;
        txtmateriales.Enabled = true;
        txtcantidadvendida.Enabled = true;
        txtmanoobra.Enabled = true;
        textBox10.Enabled = true;
        txtcodigo.Enabled = false;
        btnbuscar.Enabled = false;
        txtmateriales.Select();
    }
    else
    {
        DialogResult mensaje = MessageBox.Show("¿Desea Indagar el Codigo del producto?", "Producto No encontrado", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (mensaje == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            MaestradeDispositivosoInventario frm = new MaestradeDispositivosoInventario();
            frm.Show();
        }
        else if (mensaje == DialogResult.No)
        {
            txtcodigo.Clear();
            txtcodigo.Select();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: A esto me refería!!

Comment: si defino un using.. no me lee el codigo del string cadsql me dispara este error:"No puede ser una declaración o declaración etiquetada" o en ingles "embedded stament cannot be a declaration or labeled statement"

Comment: @SamuelIgnacioSusanaConfesor tendrías que mostrar como la estas declarando, pero cadSql es el select que se va a ejecutar

Comment: @AgustinM. si te sirvio esta solución podrías marcarla como buena?